# How can I read a CSV file from an URL to datagridview?

Tags: csv, url, datagridview

I would like to get my csv file from a website (www.google.be/test.csv) and put in into a datagridview.
I have already managed the operation with an XML file but can not find a solution to a .CSV

Did I missed something?
Thank you

Comment: could you show what you have done with XML, and also point out which part does not work for CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for XML reading from URL

```
    // Ouvrir .XML depuis le flux
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                string xml = wc.DownloadString("WWW.GOOGLE.BE/TEST.XML");

                StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);

                XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xtr);

                bs.DataSource = ds;
                bs.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

                label1.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString() + " produits à mettre à jour";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```